# No items. displayed when trying to add pages to my menu

Tags: database, wordpress, menu, admin

So, today i have the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647172/unable-to-change-front-page-no-items-displayed-on-menu-nav-wordpress).

It happenes under Appearance - Menus when i try to add more pages to my custom menu. Search option works but when i hit **View All** to browse all pages, then i am able to browse first two pages, other pages return **No pages.** text.

What might be wrong?

Comment: is there you pages publish ? and one other thing you have select "primary menu" checkbox ?

Comment: Yes, my pages are published nad i have selected menu properly.

Comment: It is related to corrupt database and if i reinstalled, then everything worked good again.